# Read each lines from an input file and print desired matched patterns

Tags: shell, if-statement, awk, while-loop, case

I have the following details captured in a input.txt file from a command. My requirement is to match the patterns "Stopped|Aborted|isn't running" in any of the lines, need to print
that line. And if the all are in "Running" state need to print a single message that "ALL ARE RUNNING".

input.txt:

```
SVRSVC1 SVRSVC1 NAME    SVRSVC1 PID     Running
SVRSVC2 SVRSVC2 NAME    SVRSVC2 PID     Running
SVRSVC3 SVRSVC3 NAME    SVRSVC3 PID     Running
SVRSVC4 SVRSVC4 NAME    SVRSVC4 PID     Running
SVRSVC5 SVRSVC5 NAME    SVRSVC5 PID     isn't running
SVRSVC6 SVRSVC6 NAME    SVRSVC6 PID     Running
SVRSVC7 SVRSVC7 NAME    SVRSVC7 PID     Running
SVRSVC8 SVRSVC8 NAME    SVRSVC8 PID     Aborted
SVRSVC9 SVRSVC9 NAME    SVRSVC9 PID     Running
SVRSVC10 SVRSVC10 NAME  SVRSVC10 PID    Running
SVRSVC11 SVRSVC11 NAME  SVRSVC11 PID    Running
SVRSVC12 SVRSVC12 NAME  SVRSVC12 PID    Stopped
SVRSVC13 SVRSVC13 NAME  SVRSVC13 PID    Running
SVRSVC14 SVRSVC14 NAME  SVRSVC14 PID    Running
```

I have the following code written but would like to know if this is a right approach. ? Please help.

```
#set -x
RUNTIME=`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`
TOTAL_RUNSTAT=$(more input.txt | wc -l)
while read -r line; do
if [[ $line =~ Stopped|Aborted|"isn't running" ]]; then
 echo $line;
 elif [[ $line =~ Running ]]; then
  echo $line >> runstatuslog_$RUNTIME;
    if [[ `more runstatuslog_$RUNTIME | wc -l` =~ $TOTAL_RUNSTAT ]]; then
         echo "ALL SERVICES RUNNING";
    fi
fi
done < input.txt
```

My desired output would be like this, If any matched pattern "Stopped|Aborted|isn't running" in the lines.

```
SVRSVC5 SVRSVC5 NAME    SVRSVC5 PID     isn't running
SVRSVC8 SVRSVC8 NAME    SVRSVC8 PID     Aborted
SVRSVC12 SVRSVC12 NAME  SVRSVC12 PID    Stopped
```

If no matched pattern in the lines & all are "Running" then print "ALL ARE RUNNING"

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why don't you use `grep`?

Answer (score 0):

```
tag=1
while read -r line; do
if [[ $line =~ Stopped|Aborted|"isn't running" ]]; then
    echo $line
tag=0
fi
done < input.txt
if [ $tag -eq 1 ]
then
echo "ALL ARE RUNNING"
fi
```

Try this. It worked for me.

Comment: This looks like explicitly putting a variable "tag=1" and taking the assumption that all are running it print the message "ALL ARE RUNNING"

Comment: Can we use "case" statement in this scenario, Any thoughts or solutions would be highly appreciated.